# Missing Email and Customers Name Guest

Tags: guest-checkout

How does this happen? This is the order page summary, normally the "`Customer Group`" for customers who aren't logged in is "`NOT LOGGED IN`". 
We are using EE 1.13.1.0 with Magestore One step checkout extension.

[image]

Comment: Which checkout do you use? Is it default one or third party?

Comment: Magestore One Step Checkout

Comment: Please contact the extension vendor.

Answer (score 1):

There's clearly also some additional customization on that Account Info block, so I'd say this is off-topic. You'll just need to debug it.

You can try starting from the template file responsible for that block and go from there. Normally, it's `adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml`.